# how to create wrapper around std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have a function object `typedef std::function<bool(Event*)> Handler`. A member function always gets assigned to this object. So, I am using `std::bind` to achieve that.

```
Handler f = std::bind(&LevelSystem::switchLevel, this, std::placeholders::_1);
f(new Event("test"));
```

This code above works as expected, but I want to wrap the `std::bind` in a helper function for cleaner code. This is what I have come up with.

```
 template<class Func> inline Handler MemFn(Func &&f) {
     return std::bind(f, this, std::placeholders::_1);
  }
```

And the usage will be:

```
 Handler f = MemFn(&LevelSystem::switchLevel);
```

I am getting an error when using this function:

```
No viable conversion from
'__bind<bool(LevelSystem::*&)(Event *), System *,std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to
'Handler' (aka 'function<bool(Event *)>')
```

I do not understand the error.

Comment: What is the context of `this` inside `MemFn`?

Comment: It is System which is the base class of LevelSystem. I changed the code to accept LevelSystem; still doesn't work

Comment: I fixed the problem by passing this as a separate parameter: `template<class Sys, class Func> inline Handler MemFn(Func &&f, Sys * system) {...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to create a bind expression that will call a `bool (LevelSystem::*)(Event*)` function on a `System` object, which is not possible.

You need to bind the correct dynamic type of `this` to the function, as your comment indicates you've now done by passing the `this` pointer to `MemFn`.

If you're always going to pass a pointer-to-member-function to `MemFn` then there's no point passing it by rvalue-reference, you might as well just pass the pointer-to-member. Doing that allows you to deduce the class type, so you can then cast `this` to that type:

```cpp
template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename Param>
  inline Handler MemFn(Ret (Class::*f)(Param)) {
    return std::bind(f, static_cast<Class*>(this), std::placeholders::_1);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! C++ keeps amazing me more and more :) One thing though. Shouldn't it be `static_cast<Class*>(this)`